# Parallel recursion in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

```
    class CustomData
    {
       public int TNum;
       public int TResult;
    }

    public static int F_recursion(int n, int w)
    {
        if (n == 0 || w == 0)
            return 0;
        else if (s[n] > w)
            return F_recursion(n - 1, w);
        else
        {
            return Math.Max(F_recursion(n - 1, w),
                p[n] + F_recursion(n - 1, w - s[n]));
        }
    }

    public static int F_recursion2(int n, int w)
    {
        int numba = 0;
        int countCPU = 8;
        Task[] tasks = new Task[countCPU];
          for (var j = 0; j < countCPU; j++)
            tasks[j] = Task.Factory.StartNew(
               (object p) =>
               {
                 var data = p as CustomData; if (data == null) return;
                   data.TResult = F_recursion(n - data.TNum, w);
               },
            new CustomData() { TNum = j });
          Task.WaitAll(tasks);
          numba = (tasks[0].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult
          + (tasks[1].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult
          + (tasks[2].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult
          + (tasks[3].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult;

        return numba;
    }
```

How could i make F_recursion2 method to work in parallel? With my code current results are

```
Time in milliseconds for recursion:  1,075
recursion(  150 ) =     7,237
Time in milliseconds for parallel recursion:  1,581
recursion(  150 ) =    28,916
```

As you can see parallel approach prints 4 times bigger number and it takes more time to compute which doesn't make sense. How could I approach this problem that recursion would work in parallel?

**EDIT** Changed for loop to `Parallel.For` still same results as above.

```
    public static int F_recursion2(int n, int w)
    {
        int numba = 0;
        int countCPU = 8;
        Task[] tasks = new Task[countCPU];
        Parallel.For(0, countCPU, j =>
       {
           tasks[j] = Task.Factory.StartNew(
              (object p) =>
              {
                  var data = p as CustomData; if (data == null) return;
                  data.TResult = F_recursion(n - data.TNum, w);
              },
           new CustomData() { TNum = j });
       });
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        numba = (tasks[0].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult
        + (tasks[1].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult
        + (tasks[2].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult
        + (tasks[3].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult;

        return numba;
    }
```

Comment: So, you should remove Task.Factory in parallel for!

Comment: Are `F_recursion2` intended to be parallel version of `F_recursion`?

Comment: Yes, it should be parallel of F_recursion

Comment: @Simas Then you need to rethink your parallel logic. Currently you just spawn eight independent tasks (`F_recursion(n, w)`, `F_recursion(n-1, w)`, ..., `F_recursion(n-7, w)` in parallel and sum results of first four of them.

Comment: I agree with you but I have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: You should split the recursion like in this post:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/207314/password-generator-with-multiple-charset

Answer (score 0):

On solution which comes to my mind is using `Parallel.For`. To do this, you should just implement the `for` using `Parallel.For`. To see an example, visit [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I changed for loop to Paralle.For but it still prints same results.

Comment: So, share your `Paralell.For` code version, to consider.